# Why does MCMC estimate the variance in a logit-normal model incorrectly?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, beta-distribution, beta-regression, logit-normal-distribution

I am trying to estimate the variance $\varepsilon^2_X$ in a simple logit-normal model of the form

- $ \sigma^{-1}(U) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_U, \varepsilon^2_U)$
- $ \sigma^{-1}(X) \sim \mathcal{N}(\sigma^{-1}(U), \varepsilon^2_X)$

where $\sigma^{-1}$ is the [logit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) and both variables $U$ and $X$ are observed. (I am assuming a relatively uninformative Gamma prior on $\varepsilon^2_X$.)

Now, when I try to identify this parameter using MCMC/NUTS$^*$ from data simulated using $\varepsilon^2_X=1$, I obtain a wildly incorrect median estimate of $\hat{\varepsilon}^2_X\approx 30$.  Why is that?

$^*$ I use numpyro, 8 chains à 500 (warmup) + 2000 steps. rhat is < 1.01 for all variables, all chains converge to the same distributions, no autocorrelation visible in the trace plots.

Answer (score 6):

This is a specific issue with the logit-normal distribution: since the noise is on the level of the logits, noise observations are of the form $\epsilon = \mathrm{logit}(X) - \mathrm{logit}(U)$. I assume that issues arise due to the general ugliness of the logit function around 0/1. Modeling $X$ as following a beta distribution instead solves the issue, and the variance can be identified nicely. Also see [Andrew Heiss' excellent blog post on beta regression](https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2021/11/08/beta-regression-guide/index.html) for alternative approaches and useful reparameterizations of the beta distribution.